# How to order the bar graph in plotly even where a value is duplicated?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to create a bar graph in dash app using plotly. My sample data looks like this

| Emp ID | Date | Day | Time Span | Duration | Hour Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 20-04-2022 | Wednesday | 09:15 AM - 12:30 PM | 3.25 | Ordinary Hours |
| 0001 | 20-04-2022 | Wednesday | 12:30 PM - 01:00 PM | 0.5 | break |
| 0001 | 20-04-2022 | Wednesday | 01:00 PM - 05:00 PM | 4 | Ordinary Hours |

My code looks like this

```
def update_hourly_table_graph(selected_date, selected_employee, selected_pay_cycle, data):
    if all(item is not None for item in [selected_date, selected_employee, selected_pay_cycle, data]):
        ctx = dash.callback_context
        if ctx.triggered:
            daily_data = [dict_ for dict_ in data["hourly_outcome"] if dict_["Employee ID"] == selected_employee["employee_id"] ]
            daily_df = pd.DataFrame(daily_data)
            print(daily_df)
            df = pd.DataFrame(filtered_data)
            print(df)
            fig = px.bar(daily_df, x='Duration', y='Date', color = 'Hour Type',text="Time Span", orientation='h', title="Audit bar graph", 
                        #  width=800, height=400,
                         color_discrete_map={"Ordinary Hours":"#119DFF", 
                                                  "break":"#EDEB79",
                                                  "Overtime":"#CA140A" })
            fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(categoryorder="array",categoryarray=df["Duration"].tolist()))
            print(daily_df["Duration"].tolist())

        return dcc.Graph(figure=fig,className="table_style", config={'displayModeBar': False})
```

I want to create a bar graph based on the same sequence in which the data is displayed (ordinary hours, break, ordinary hours). My problem is that the bars combine the two ordinary hours row and display it in this order (ordinary hours, ordinary hours, break).
I tried ordering the display using category order, but it must still be in the expected order. This is how it is currently displayed, and I want to avoid this order.[image]

Note: The hour type order is not the same always. It keeps changing and for every employee. Sometimes there will be overtime, and others as well.
Can someone please help? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `go.Bar` instead of `px.bar`. Something as below may help:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

test_df = pd.read_excel('Ordinary Hours.xlsx')
test_df.loc[test_df['Hour Type'] == 'Ordinary Hours', 'Color'] = 'Blue'
test_df.loc[test_df['Hour Type'] == 'break', 'Color'] = 'Yellow'
test_df.loc[test_df['Hour Type'] == 'Overtime', 'Color'] = 'Red'

fig = go.Figure()

legend_show_dict = {}
for i, row in test_df.iterrows():
    if row['Hour Type'] in legend_show_dict:
        legend_show = legend_show_dict[row['Hour Type']]
    else:
        legend_show = True
        legend_show_dict[row['Hour Type']] = False
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Bar(
            x=[row['Duration']],
            y=[row['Date']],
            marker_color=row['Color'],
            name=row['Hour Type'],
            legendgroup=row['Hour Type'],
            orientation='h',
            showlegend=legend_show,
            text=[row['Time Span']],
            textposition='inside',
            hovertemplate="<br>".join([
            'Time Span: ' + str(row['Time Span']),
            'Duration: ' + str(row['Duration']),
            ])
           ))
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis={'categoryorder': 'category ascending', 'title': 'Duration'},
    yaxis={'title': 'Date'},
    legend={'traceorder': 'normal'}
    )
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack', font_size=20)
fig.show()
```

[image]